# Multiply keys*values in a dict?

Tags: python

```
a = {2: 4, 3: 2, 5: 1, 7: 1}
```

The keys represent prime numbers; the values represent counters. I want to calculate the number you get by iterating through the dictionary keys*values and summing the total. What is the most Pythonic way to do this?

```
>>> [k*v for k,v in a.items()]
[8, 6, 5, 7]
```

but

```
>>> sum(k*v for k,v in a.items())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Comment: The general way you iterate through (key,value) tuples is with `yourDict.items()`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This way:

```
sum(k*v for k,v in a.items())
```

or with semantic naming:

```
sum(p*c for p,c in primesToCounts.items())
```

Comment: @Chris: `a` should be your dictionary. For example in your question you said `a = {2: 4, 3: 2, 5: 1, 7: 1}`. I don't believe that you are calling those two things in the same way. This method works in both python2 and python3. If you find you still have the error above, type `a` into your interpreter you will find something silly like `a==5`.

Comment: @Chris: Your problem is that you defined a variable called `sum` which shadowed the built-in function called `sum`. Type `sum` into your current interpreter: `23` or something. Now type `sum` into a clean interpreter: `<function ...>`. You are likely trying to do `23(k*v for k,v in a.items())`

Comment: You are correct. Whoops... valuable lesson learned. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
>>> a = {2: 4, 3: 2, 5: 1, 7: 1}
>>> [key * val for key, val in a.items()]
... [8, 6, 5, 7]
>>> sum([key * val for key, val in a.items()])
... 26
```

That's pretty pythonic.