# Multiply key*value in a list inside a dictionary?

Tags: python

`a = {u'1': ['abc', 'thanks', 2.0, 999.0],u'2': ['def', 'for', 2.0, 100.0],u'3': ['ghi', 'helping', 1.0, 99999.0],u'4': ['jkl', 'me', 3.0, 2120.0] etc:[etc]}`

So I'm trying to have all multiply all the Dictionary { key : List [ blah, blah, **numbers**, **numbers**], key : List [ blah, blah, **numbers**, **numbers** ], etc} This is proving very troublesome :(. The output I want is `108557` which is derived from (2*999)+(2*100)+(1*99999)+(3*2120).

I found an answer here [Multiply keys*values in a dict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865979/multiply-keysvalues-in-a-dict) that nearly solves my problem. In that he's able to multiply this dictionary `a = {2: 4, 3: 2, 5: 1, 7: 1}` to get an answer of `26` by using `sum([key * val for key, val in a.items()])`. I'm having trouble incorporating the list in this code! Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the numbers are **always** the last two elements, you could do:

```
sum([val[-2] * val[-1] for val in a.values()])
```

**edit** updated with Blckknght's tip

Comment: You can just iterate over the `values` view, since you don't need the key at all.